# How do you unlock these locked chests in Europa?

Tags: destiny-2

[image]

Found this chest in Bray Exoscience in the main hall.  Has a locked symbol with a weird icon I haven't seen before.

How do I unlock these chests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that the accepted answer implies that you will learn how to unlock these weirdly locked chests as you progress through the campaign; however, I'd still like to add a solid answer covered by a spoiler:

> These chests are locked by Stasis. You can see a unique blue symbol in the action prompt when you move close to these chests, which is a Stasis symbol. In order to unlock the chests, you must first use your Splinter of Darkness (which is simply a quest step) while progressing through the campaign and **attune the respective symbol** at the Ziggurat. Then, **commune** with a Crux of Darkness (marked as a waypoint on your map). Once you finish this step, you can unlock chests sealed by that symbol.

Comment: Not quite right on the quest progress to do it. Each quest step that leads to a new attunement is, Receive Splinter -> Attune at Ziggurat -> Commune at specific Crux of Darkness -> Capable of unlocking all chests/doors with that symbol.

Comment: Ah, I must've missed the step where I had to commune with a Crux of Darkness. I was under the impression that once the symbol is attuned, all the chests locked by that symbol are unlocked. Please let me add this to my answer.

Comment: Why do you have this covered by a spoiler? This is/was covered in the triumphs page in the game.

Comment: To avoid spoiling the solution for those who just want a hint, not the full answer

Answer (score 3):

To avoid any spoilers, you should just progress the campaign, as you do so each of the locked chests will become capable of being unlocked.

Complete the quests as they come up and you'll even be tasked with hunting down specific chests.